# Prenex form of the power set axiom

Tags: set-theory

I began teaching myself Zermelo-Fraenkel Set Theory today, and decided to test myself by writing down all the axioms I have read about without looking at the notes. On the axiom of power set, I wrote down:

$\forall a\exists y\forall x(x \in y \iff \forall z(z \in x \rightarrow z \in a))$

On looking at my notes, I see the actual definition is:

$\forall a\exists y\forall x\forall z(x \in y \iff (z \in x \rightarrow z \in a))$

My question is, was there any difference between what I wrote down and what is written in my notes?

Comment: Thanks @AndresCaicedo, so does it follow from what you have said that we can always bring quantifiers to the beginning of the sentence? I ask since in my notes the axiom of union is written as $\forall a\exists y\forall x(x \in y \iff \exists z(x \in z \wedge z \in a))$. So could we have brought the $\exists z$ out to the front of this sentence?

Comment: Isn't the second one inconsistent? Let $a = \{0\}$ and $z = 0$. Then $\forall x(0\in x \to 0 \in \{0\})$ because $0\in\{0\}$. So $\forall x(x\in y)$. What am I missing?

Comment: @GME What you have shown does not mean $\forall x(x \in y)$ since we require that $\forall z(z \in x \rightarrow z \in a)$, and you have only shown this statement is true for $z = 0$.

Comment: Here's the argument in a little more detail: instantiate $a$ and $z$ as I said. Then we have some $y$ such that $\forall x(x\in y \leftrightarrow (z\in x \to z\in a))$. It follows that $\forall x(x\in y) \leftrightarrow \forall x(z\in x \to z\in a)$. Now, by propositional logic we have $z\in a \to (z\in x \to z\in a)$. So, we have $\forall x (z\in a) \to \forall x(z\in x \to z\in a)$. But because $z\in a$ and the variable $x \not = a, z$, we also have $\forall x(z\in a)$. So, $\forall x(z\in x \to z\in a)$ and thus $\forall x(x\in y)$. Where do you think that argument goes wrong?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, which book are you using?

Comment: @GME once again, you are saying instantiate $z$ as $z = 0$. You are correct that in this instance it is true that $\forall x(0 \in x \rightarrow 0 \in a)$. However the axiom states that this must be true $\forall z$. So if $x = \{1\}$, if we choose $z = 1$ then the statement $(z \in x \rightarrow z \in a)$ fails, so $x \not\in a$

Comment: @AlexBowring I'm not quite following. Which line of the proof I gave do you think is wrong?

Comment: Okay, in your proof you have set $z = 0$. Then everything you write is certainly correct, until at the end you say 'So, $\forall x(z \in x \rightarrow z \in a)$ and thus $\forall x(x \in y)$.' This is incorrect, just read the statement of the axiom, for $x \in y$ we require that $\forall z (z \in x \rightarrow z \in a)$ and in your whole proof you only show $\forall x(0 \in x \rightarrow 0 \in a)$.

Comment: Good. So, you deny that $\forall x(z\in x \to z\in a)$. But that follows from $\forall x(z\in a)$ (because $z\in a \to (z\in x \to z\in a)$ is an axiom of propositional logic). And that, in turn, follows from $z\in a$ (because $z\in a \to \forall x(z\in a)$ is an axiom of quantificational logic). And $z\in a$ is true by definition of $z$ and $a$.

Comment: BTW: on the second formulation it's exactly because it only requires $(z\in x \to z\in a)$ and not $\forall z(z\in x\to z\in a)$ (like the first formulation) that it's inconsistent. Could you say where you found the second formulation?

Comment: '$z \in a$ is true by definition of $z$ and $a$', yes, it does when you set $z = 0$. Now set $z$ equal to any other number and the whole argument breaks down. The formulation is in the notes on the Set Theory by Adam Epstein for the Warwick University module, I can not share them with you but if you look around online you may find them.

Comment: $\forall z\phi(z) \to \phi(x)$ (where $x$ is free for $z$ in $\phi$) is an axiom of quantificational logic.

Comment: You ask "the axiom of union is written as ∀a∃y∀x(x∈y⟺∃z(x∈z∧z∈a)). So could we have brought the ∃z out to the front of this sentence?" It can be done but it's not pretty: $\forall a\exists y\forall x\forall z((x \in z \in a  \rightarrow x \in y) \wedge ((z \in a \rightarrow x \notin z) \rightarrow x \notin y))$

Comment: @DavidHartley Let $x\in y$ and $z$ be such that $x\not\in z$. Then the second conjunct implies $x\not\in y$ after all.

Comment: Ah, drat. I hadn't noticed the quantifies in the second sentence were in the wrong order. Sorry.

Comment: (So, no. The two statements are not equivalent, but I suspect there is a typo here.)

Comment: Indeed you are correct, I did make a typo which I unfortunately have only spotted now you have drawn my attention to it, I have now edited the second sentence to how it should be. @GME, with the second sentence as it is now do you agree the axiom is consistent? Apologies to you both for the typo, if it is any constellation the question has now been much more constructive for myself - I now know that both bringing a quantifier to the front and the order of quantifiers at the front can significantly change a sentence - so thank you both for the consideration you have given to this

Comment: @AlexBowring I'm actually not sure it is. If you let $x$ be any set and $z$ any set such that $z\not\in x$, it will follow that $x\in y$. Since there's always such a $z$ for any $x$, $\forall x(x\in y)$. (Ps: yes, the order of quantifiers is super important!)

Comment: @GME You seem to have correctly identified flaws in all the attempts here to bring all quantifiers to the beginning (including mine). The problem seems to be that $\forall z\phi(z) \iff \psi$ is not equivalent to $\forall z(\phi(z) \iff \psi)$ (where z is not free in $\psi$). Is there any way around that?

Comment: @GME: yes the order of quantifiers is very important; but the problem here is not about the order of the quantifiers but their "sense": universal quantifiers turn into existential quantifiers when you move them from negative positions to positive positions. In the case of a bi-implication, you have to split it into two implications so you can distinguish properly between the positive and negative positions.

Comment: @RobArthan Sure; I didn't claim otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct statement of the power set axiom is the first sentence you wrote down:

$$\forall a\exists y\forall x(x \in y \iff \forall z(z \in x \rightarrow z \in a))$$

I.e., for every set $a$, there is a set $y$ (the power set of $a$) whose members are the subsets of $a$, i.e., the sets $x$, such that every member $z$ of $x$ is also a member of $a$.

This is not equivalent to the sentence you describe as the "actual definition" with the quantification over $z$ moved outside the bi-implication. That must be an error in your notes, since given any set $x$, you could pick $z \not\in x$ and use it to conclude that $x$ is a member of the power set of any set $a$.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form for how to move quantifiers outside the propositional connectives. When you put $\phi \iff \psi$ into prenex normal form, you need to treat it as $(\phi \Rightarrow \psi) \land (\psi \Rightarrow \phi)$ and the result will be a mess for the power set axiom ($z$ will be universally quantified in one conjunct and existentially quantified in the other).

Comment: Concerning "you need to treat it as $(\phi\implies\psi)\land(\psi\implies\phi)$": Alternatively, you could treat it as $(\phi\land\psi)\lor((\neg\phi)\land(\neg\psi))$. But it would still be the case that "the result will be a mess".

Comment: So it looks like the prenex normal form of the power set axiom should be $\forall a\exists y\forall x\forall z\exists t((x \in y \rightarrow (z \in x \rightarrow z \in a)) \wedge ((t \in x \rightarrow t \in a) \rightarrow x \in y))$

Comment: @David Hartley: that looks right to me.